# How to start app/program with defined input language

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

I have a german keyboard layout and german as input language. However, some programs do not accept a comma as decimal for number input. A dot is required for input.

For a way better workflow, I want to be able to create a dot with the button on the num-pad, where in german layout, there is a comma.

What works fine is, to change the settings that each application can have a different input language, start the app, change the language and then it works.

I want this to happen automatically.
Is there a way to run certain apps with a certain input language permanently? Is there maybe a startup parameter which I can add in the shortcut path to the exe file? The language name would be "en-US", but I did not find a list with startup parameters. Are they specific to the app or are there "general" parameters, that work on every windows program?

Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a Windows Process can have its own input method, the selection of a keyboard layout is set for the current user not a process.

You create a shortcut that starts a PowerShell script that first changes the input method to `us-US` and then starts your application.

Of course this will also changes the input method for all other applications.

But you can always quickly change it back by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

I don't know how to pick the input method in PowerShell, but you can use this code to set both input methods, the first one is the one that is active:

```
$UserLanguageList = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language "en-US"
$UserLanguageList.Add("de-DE")
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $UserLanguageList -Force
```

Comment: In Windows 10 there is an option to set an input language for each application.

When I start windows and start applications, they all have german layout. But I applied the setting in windows options: Start > Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Additional date, time & regional settings > (under Language) Change input methods > Advanced settings > (under switching input methods) Check on "Let me set a different input method for each app window"

Now I can switch the language for one open application and when I switch between applications, the language switches perfectly.

Comment: I do not want to use a hotkey for quick changing.

I know how to set the input language.

It is enabled to switch between languages for different apps.


I want windows to "remember" the language or set the language for an application on application start.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Let me set a different input method for each app window` setting, thanks. But it looks like you can only change this during runtime, it is not saved in the registry anywhere. Maybe someone else has an answer.